# XPath expressions?

Tags: xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Patients>
  <patientRole>
    <id extension="996-756-495" root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
    <id extension="775-756-495" root="2.16.840.1.113883.14.6"/>
    <patient>
      <name>
        <given>Henry</given>
        <family>Levin</family>
      </name>
      <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
      <birthTime value="19320924"/>
    </patient>
    <providerOrganization>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
      <name>Good Health Clinic</name>
    </providerOrganization>
    <admissionTime value="2012030111:32"/>
  </patientRole>
  <patientRole>
    <id extension="65" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.933"/>
    <patient>
      <name>
        <given>Paul</given>
        <family>Pappel</family>
      </name>
      <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
      <birthTime value="19551217"/>
    </patient>
    <providerOrganization>
      <id extension="84756-11241-283-OPTD-3322" root="1.2.3.4.5.6.1.8.9.0"/>
      <name> Dr.med. Hans Topp-Glucklich</name>
    </providerOrganization>
    <admissionTime value="201201152200"/>
  </patientRole>
  <patientRole>
    <id extension="800001" root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
    <patient>
      <name>
        <given>JEANNE</given>
        <family>PETIT</family>
      </name>
      <administrativeGenderCode code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
      <birthTime value="19480105"/>
    </patient>
    <providerOrganization>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
      <name>Good Health Clinic</name>
    </providerOrganization>
    <admissionTime value="20120101T22:00"/>
  </patientRole>
</Patients>
```

I am having difficulty writing XPath expressions for the following two items:

Given and family name of the patient born on 17 Dec 1955

Number of patients admitted to "Good Health Clinic" in January 2012

Comment: This is sample data, right? Not patient-identifiable data?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the `name` element of the patients born on the particular date:

```
patientRole/patient[birthTime/@value="19551217"]/name
```

This will get you the count of `patientRole` elements with the organisation name and admission date specified:

```
count(patientRole[providerOrganization/name="Good Health Clinic"][starts-with(admissionTime/@value,"201201")])
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why but I have the same info regarding the name elment of patients born on 19551217 but it still comes up wrong on my homework.